# search multiple value through one textbox

Tags: c#

Here , when we enter folder name in `input.text` then it will search for that folder in D drive and return its path in `Path.text`.
its is working fine for the single name entered in `input.text`
but i want to search multiple folder name at time in `input.text` and want its path in `Path.text`.

for example :

> ABC,EFG,XYZ

these three value i  entered in `input.text`

```
private void button1_Click (object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    string[] dirs = Directory.GetDirectories(D:\, input.Text + "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);

    foreach (string dir in dirs)
    {    
        Path.Text =dir.ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you already try to split the text "ABC,EFG,XYZ" (and any number of follwing texts), loop through the result and check the directories accordingly? OK, this MIGHT lead to duplicates in cases where one directory matches multiple strings, but this can be handled afterwards...

Comment: beware! the option: `SearchOption.AllDirectories` might throw an exception if you don't have the rights to access some directories.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:
Split at first all entered directories
then for each single entry call your function.
And to add more Text to your TextBox use `+=`

```
private void button1_Click (object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    string [] individualDirs = input.Text.Split(',');

    foreach (string one_dir in individualDirs)
    { 

        string[] dirs = Directory.GetDirectories(@"D:\", one_dir + "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);

        foreach (string dir in dirs)
        {   // to add more Text to your TextBox use +=
            Path.Text += dir.ToString() + Environment.NewLine;
        }
    }
}
```

Another possibility could also be to use Linq and do it in one blow:

```
string [] individualDirs = input.Text.Split(',');

List<string> dirslinq = individualDirs.SelectMany(x => Directory.GetDirectories(@"C:\", x + "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)).ToList();

Path.Text = String.Join("\n", dirslinq);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to split the text with comma, refer below code :

```
        var folderNames = input.Text.Split(',');
        string[] dirs = null;
        foreach (var folder in folderNames)
        {
            dirs = Directory.GetDirectories(@"D:\", folder + "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
        }

        foreach (string dir in dirs)
        {
            Path.Text += dir.ToString() + ", ";
        }
```

Comment: wouldn't this produce only the output from the last entry in `folderNames` ? to have all matches you would need to nest the 2nd loop into the 1st

Answer (score 0):

If you seperate the values for which you are searching with for example comma's, you can then with the `substring` command feed the extracted values to your code, and run it multiple times